# Turning on Nullable warnings in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, nullable

I am setting up my Intellij environment and I am wondering how to turn on Nullable warnings for the following:

```
Map<String, String> simpleMap = new HashMap<>();
String thisWillBeNull = simpleMap.get("key");
int l = thisWillBeNull.length();  //<-- how do I get a Nullable warning here?
```

Comment: "how do I get a NullPointerException here?" Why do you think you can get NPE there? `this` is never null. Do you mean `thisWillBeNull.length()`? (But in general, I doubt you can really detect that `thisWillBeNull` *will* be null, as opposed to merely Nullable).

Comment: That's probably too complex to detect by the IDE. It doesn't know the state of the Map. If you did `String thisWillBeNull = null;` instead, the IDE should be able to detect it.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson it shouldn't be too hard, the Map [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) states that `get(...)` can return `null`.

Comment: "Can" doesn't mean that it always will do. That's a big difference.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson right, but I just want Intellij to tell me that it "can" be null.

Comment: I don't see the point. Every variable in your code "can" be null. It's only interesting to be told by the IDE when a variable will always be null.

Comment: A variable won't be null if it comes from a nonnull method. Additionally it is good to know when a variable can be null so that null checks can be performed.

Comment: Indeed, this particular situation could be detected. Try kotlin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ's nullity analysis is useful, but limited.  It has weak handling for maps.

If you wish to obtain guarantees about code that uses maps, you could use the [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker), which includes a [map key analysis](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#map-key-checker).
It isn't built into IntelliJ, but you can [integrate it with IntelliJ](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#intellij) or run it as a separate tool.

Given this code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapGetTest {
  void m() {
    Map<String, String> simpleMap = new HashMap<>();
    String thisWillBeNull = simpleMap.get("key");
    int l = thisWillBeNull.length();
  }
}
```

You can run this command:

```
javac -processor nullness MapGetTest.java
```

and the result is:

```
MapGetTest.java:8: error: [dereference.of.nullable] dereference of possibly-null reference thisWillBeNull
    int l = thisWillBeNull.length();
            ^
1 error
```

Comment: I do like this solution! The only problem I am getting now is that if `simpleMap` is populated somewhere else then I still get this error...

Comment: Can you post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (probably in a different question)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Intellij:

Go to Analyze -> Inspect Code

This will analyze the code and point out possible issues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, two things are needed to give tools a chance to detect the problem:

- analysis must use null annotations to enable inter-procedural analysis
- method `Map.get()` must be annotated to return `@Nullable V`. For library classes this may happen using external annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, so I asked a similar question in [Intellij community](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289285#focus=Comments-27-5802422.0-0)

Here is the answer: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289285#focus=Comments-27-5802422.0-0

### Solution

1. add `@Nullable` to `java.util.Map` interface
2. create a new Structural Search Inspection. However, it seems that you cannot share this config with your team by git directly.

[image]